# Unexpected result with list.count(True) in Python

Tags: python, list, count, boolean

I am encountering an unexpected behavior in Python when using the `list.count()` method. The issue arises when counting occurrences of `True` in a list where `True` is not explicitly added or appended to the list. The count seems to be reported as 2, even though True is expected only once in the list.

Here is an example:

```py
my_list = [1, 2.5, 'isa', False, True]

# Counting occurrences of True
count_of_true = my_list.count(True)

print(count_of_true)  # Output: 2 (unexpected)
```

In this example, `count_of_true` is unexpectedly reported as 2, even though `True` is not explicitly added to the list more than once.

I have checked the code and confirmed that `True` is not appended or added to the list elsewhere. The count for `False` is correctly reported as 1.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into why `list.count(True)` might be behaving unexpectedly in this scenario?

Comment: `True==1`, as you could easily check by trying different subsets of your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that 1 == True (and 0 == False).

To exclude 1 for True (and 0 for False, if needed), there's an `is` operator. This operator doesn't compare the two operands, instead, it compares their position in memory.

To resolve the issue, consider using a more ugly (but working) code, like this:

```py
my_list = [1, 2.5, 'isa', False, True]
count_of_true = sum(1 for item in my_list if item is True)  # this
print(count_of_true) # prints 1
```

Comment: Bingo, That's a clever solution! Thanks buddy.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad the solution worked for you.